# Installing new fonts - system memory, speed, cache…

Tags: font

in the past year I have installed around 1500 different free fonts and uninstalled around 1400, so I’m left let’s say with 100 fonts.

My question is whether permanently adding/removing new fonts (and now having around 100 fonts non-default fonts) have any impact/s on the *macOS* speed - whether the *macOS* has to load all the new fonts with opening certain Apps (or on the start-up), whether every font store some cache which remains after the font is removed and so on…

Thanks

Comment: Do you experience any specific performance issues related to fonts?

Comment: I don't, but my MB seems to be slowing down a bit lately, so I was wondering whether it might be related to huge number of fonts which I install / remove on a daily basis.